# Snowflake foreign keys aren't created when using ON UPDATE/ON DELETE actions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables created like this

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
                         id int AUTOINCREMENT(6,1) NOT NULL,
                         first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                         last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                         PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
                       id int NOT NULL,
                       author_id int NOT NULL,
                       content text NOT NULL
);
```

And i want to add foreign key.

Statement
`ALTER TABLE posts ADD CONSTRAINT fk_posts_authors_test FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES authors (id)` works fine.

Statement `ALTER TABLE posts ADD CONSTRAINT fk_posts_authors_test FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES authors (id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT` is executed without error, but foreign key isn't created

I read that Snowflake doesn't enforce constraints(except not null) but silently fail creating foreign key in such way is frustrating for me.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may come as a surprise, but it is correct behavior.
By default, Snowflake allows additional options when invoking a DDL action. This is to help you migrate the model from other database systems.

If you don't want your Snowflake to behave like this, just set one [UNSUPPORTED_DDL_ACTION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#unsupported-ddl-action) parameter like this:

```sql
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;

ALTER ACCOUNT SET UNSUPPORTED_DDL_ACTION = FAIL; -- Default is IGNORE
```

Changing this parameter to FAIL will result in an error message similar to this when trying to create a FK with unsupported options:

```
SQL compilation error: invalid constraint property
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also able to reproduce the issue.

Please submit a ticket to Support, so this bug can be reported to the development team.

Comment: This is know behavior in snowflake world and we see constraints get created in DB but not effective. Clearly Snowflake documentations mentioned same and there  is community post on same topic. From snowflake doc:"These properties are provided to facilitate migrating from other databases. They are not enforced or maintained by Snowflake. This means that the defaults can be changed for these properties, but changing the defaults results in Snowflake not creating the constraint."

Comment: No, this is not a known behaviour. Please read the question carefully or even repro the issue if you have some questions. The problem is not about forcing FKs or ignoring the defined actions. The statement is completed successfully without creating NOTHING. This is a bug.

Comment: I tried to repro same issue with same , constraints got created but not effective. I tried to update/delete data from authors  table which has a key referencing  in posts but nothing stopped .That made me conclusion about behaviour.I also see constraints got created in metadata tables.

Comment: Are you sure that you run only the second statement after creating the table? I'm testing it on IE (dublin) region 6.0.1 - where do you test it?

Comment: It is reproducible now, looks  I missed commenting first statement and 2 statements were executed sequentially after looking to my history. Its my bad ...

Answer (score 0):

While Gokhan, has agreed "this doesn't work", I propose "what does it matter"

There are 2 reason Snowflake has to support "Foreign Keys" syntax. Given it does not enforce them, which we are all in agreement to understanding.

1. Allow the use of other system DDL scripts to enable import data easier
2. Help external Systems makes better sense of the data. Like Looker

The #1 point is 100% happy with the result you are getting, *create table, create table, doing something that is meaningless, happy, happy*.

The second #2 point, so yes. the FK is not recorded. But the FK you are registering is that there are rules enforced, that external tools might understandably rely on, which is not how the data is. So while the FK relationship is missing which might make the external tool, "more hard to use" the answers are at least not more wrong. because of this missing FK.

So yes it's a bug, yes it could be fixed, but does it impact core snowflake usage - no, does it impact secondary system interactions - yes. Is it high priority, imho no.